# Sending authentication information to SQL Server isn't working (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-connection, sqlcommand

I already asked about a similar issue to this one but I've narrowed it down to my problem and I've been working on this for hours and unable to figure this out.

Basically, I have a visual studio wep application and I'm trying to use a login page and sql server database to validate user credentials.  The user enters a string for username and password on the log-in screen which gets sent here on the code behind:

```
private bool ValidateUser(string userName, string passWord)
        {
            SqlConnection conn;
            SqlCommand cmd;
            string lookupPassword = null;


                // Consult with your SQL Server administrator for an appropriate connection
                // string to use to connect to your local SQL Server.
                conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["databaseConnect"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();

                // Create SqlCommand to select pwd field from users table given supplied userName.
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Password from Users where User=@userName;", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
                cmd.Parameters["@userName"].Value = userName;

                lookupPassword = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            // If no password found, return false.
                 if (null == lookupPassword)
                 {
                     return false;
                 }

private void cmdLogin_ServerClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
      {
          if (ValidateUser(txtUserName.Value,txtUserPass.Value) )

           (logs in)

      }
```

The application is connected a table in a database, which currently holds one test item, as shown here:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa7kH.jpg

However, when I enter "test" as username and "password" as password, it doesn't accept the log-in.

I tried to include only the relevant parts of my code to make it more clear for anybody trying to answer the question but here's a few comments about my problem:

-When I set if (null == lookupPassword) to "return true" instead of "return false" the application allows logins.  **Which means lookupPassword is still null after "lookupPassword = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();"**

-The application works fine when I change if(ValidateUser(txtUserName.Value,txtUserPass.Value)) to if(userName=test and passWord=password).  So the problem is not with the actual act of logging into the application, it just isn't finding the SQL Server credentials to be true.

-"databaseConnect" is working elsewhere on the application, so that is not the issue.

-The application is not breaking when I submit the login credentials, it is simply not accepting them as correct.

Going off that, it seems to me that the problem comes from these four lines:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Password from Users where User=@userName;", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
cmd.Parameters["@userName"].Value = userName;

lookupPassword = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Does anybody see where the problem might be for me?  I'm very new to programming so please keep the answers as simple as possible please.  Thank you in advance for any help.  :)

Comment: What is the value of `lookupPassword` after the `ExecuteScalar` call?

Comment: From what you've said, it looks as though there's a problem with how you're accessing your user input data. What type of object is txtUsername/txtPassword?

Comment: PS. You appear to be storing plaintext passwords, consider what will happen if (due to some other vulnerability) someone gets access to the database? (It has been done many times, you are *not* different.)

Comment: @Richard Well when I change the line of [if (null == lookupPassword) {return false; }] to [if (null == lookupPassword) { return true; }] the login works.  So that would imply that lookupPassword is null after the Execute Scalar call, correct?

Comment: @alexc95 Two different textboxes, <input id="txtUserName" type="text" runat="server"> and <input id="txtUserPass" type="password" runat="server">.

Comment: @Richard I'm not really aware of the possible dangers of storing passwords as plaintext...do you know any good articles or books that I could read to become more knowledgeable of the subject and how to store my passwords more securely?

Comment: If you don't already know, then you really shouldn't be implementing authentication. But [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) looks like a reasonable start. Note that .NET includes [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) and [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) for the heavy lifting. ***But*** above all keep an eye on the tech news and see how others fail, to help you avoid the same fate.

Comment: On the subject of diagnosing this failure: use the debugger to see (1) exactly what is in the username passed to SQL Server, and exactly what is coming back. Try doing the same query manually (ie. use Sql Server Management Studio).

Comment: @Richard Okay, thanks I will look into that.  But for the issue at hand, I tried doing the SQLCommand manually in SSMS and didn't get any results, so I guess the problem is there?  Here's what I did: http://i.imgur.com/h0JNIzP.jpg

Comment: I figured it out by the way, it turns out my username and password in the SQL table had spaces that needed to be trimmed, which prevented it from matching.  Silly.

Thanks for those who answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table design is using several [reserved words](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in SQL Server. If you cannot modify this schema, you can update your query as follows:

```
SELECT [Password] FROM [Users] WHERE [User] = @Username
```

That being said, storing passwords in plaintext is a horrible security practice. Passwords should never be stored encrypted or as plaintext, they should be hashed using a salt to help avoid rainbow tables from cracking your password. I would look into the suggestion from @Richard regarding [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx). You can also search Google or Bing for using salt and SHA256.